# How to accomplish assymetric encryption with Netty without SSL

Tags: java, netty, encryption-asymmetric

I have been trying for a while to do encryption in a netty chat program I created. I have been trying to add encryption WITHOUT a certificate or SSL by encrypting the messages themselves. I have tried AES encryption and it did "succeed" but the password to decrypt the messages was plain text so it didn't do anything. I have also tried RSA encryption but I can't get it to encrypt a JSON string message

I used the RSA encryption transformation: "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"

```java
public static String encrypt(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(StaticHandler.RSA_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()), CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    }
```

## How it works currently:

The server generates a key pair only used in the initial handshake, then sends the public key to the client. Then the client generates a new key pair encrypted with the public key the server sent. Once the server receives the new key pair, it uses that instead of the one created in the initial handshake so the client can decrypt messages sent by the server.

But I can't seem to get it to work with sending a JSON string with the part of the connection handshake where the client generates a new keypair that the server will use to send encrypted messages back to the client.

I'm not necessarily asking for spoon feeding code but an explanation of how this can be handled better or an encryption protocol that is better suited for my means, though it is helpful to see code examples :p

```java
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 501 bytes
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
        at com.github.fernthedev.universal.encryption.EncryptionHandler.encrypt(EncryptionHandler.java:150)
        at com.github.fernthedev.universal.encryption.RSA.EncryptedStringEncoder.encode(EncryptedStringEncoder.java:49)
        at com.github.fernthedev.universal.encryption.RSA.EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder.encode(EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder.java:70)
        at com.github.fernthedev.universal.encryption.RSA.EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder.encode(EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder.java:16)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:763)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:789)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:757)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:812)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1037)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:293)
        at com.github.fernthedev.client.Client.sendObject(Client.java:270)
        at com.github.fernthedev.client.EventListener.received(EventListener.java:91)
        at com.github.fernthedev.client.netty.ClientHandler.channelRead(ClientHandler.java:71)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:429)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You're supposed to trade the secret key with public key cryptography (e.g. RSA), then use a block cipher (e.g. AES) with the securely exchanged key to actually secure the traffic.

Comment: @Kayaman Know any place that can explain this in a more in-depth step-by-step process? Thanks though for explaining in words what I have to do, it's more helpful than nothing :)

Comment: No. I do not know any place that explains cryptography.